# AWS S3 CLI: Anonymous users cannot initiate multipart uploads

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line, amazon-s3

I'm trying to upload a file to Amazon S3 via the command-line, but I keep receiving this error:

> A client error (AccessDenied) occurred when calling the CreateMultipartUpload operation: Anonymous users cannot initiate multipart uploads.  Please authenticate.

The command I'm running is:

```
# aws s3 cp --sse pad-20151108-175046.tar.gz s3://mpen-backups
```

I've configured `aws` via `aws configure` with what I believe are the correct credentials. `aws s3 ls` does list my buckets.

How do I provide a user to AWS CLI? My googlefu isn't turning up anything useful.

---

I installed `aws` via `apt-get install awscli` (on Ubuntu).

```
# aws --version
aws-cli/1.2.9 Python/3.4.0 Linux/3.13.0-24-generic
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Solution: take your dog(s) out for a walk.

I just came back after about 30 minutes, pressed up on my terminal and re-ran the exact same command. Uploaded fine this time.

I think either Amazon was having authentication issues when I first ran this, or maybe my S3 bucket hadn't propagated yet, but it runs fine now.

Comment: Feel free to mark as answered, or delete the question.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thank you, I know how SO works. Can't accept for another 2 days. I'm not deleting the question in case others encounter the same error, they should know that simply waiting is a potential solution.

Comment: Oops! You've got high rep. My apologies.

Comment: Thank you for not deleting the question :) I was starting to panic as this is happening to me.

Comment: I took 2 hours and 30 minutes in my case, but waiting that long fixed it.This is very incompetent on their part...

Comment: I had the same problem, and took my dog Puddings out for a walk, and it sorted itself out when I got back. +1

Comment: this took me an hour

Comment: So glad I found this. Had already spent an hour trying all sorts of things to solve it... waited 2 hours and it worked. Amazon need to improve this!

Comment: Same thing just happened to me...  AWS plz fix!

Comment: True that, may be you can switch the tool to s3cmd. For one bucket, awscli worked, and the error popped up. And finally s3cmd worked.

Comment: same thing happened to me. took the dog for a walk, took neighbor's dog for a walk... still not working. Any other solutions?

Answer (score 2):

I couldnt upload even when i tried IAM Role, config file and ENV Variables.

In my case it was a Repo installed AWSCLI, specifically on Debian 8.6:

`awscli/stable,now 1.4.2-1 all [installed]`

Removed it and installed with pip as recommended by [AWS Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/awscli-install-linux.html)

Works now.

Answer (score 1):

In my case this message was displayed because the user trying to copy the file to s3 doesn't have permission to.
To fix it was adding user write permission to the s3 bucket.